# How to create a new df with pandas based on a set of conditions that compares each row by the others within the same df?

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to use pandas to create a new df based on a set of conditions that compares the rows from one another within the original df. I am new to using pandas and feel comfortable comparing two df from one another and basic column comparisons, but for some reason the row by row comparison is stumping me. My specific conditions and problem are found below:

```
    Cosine_i_    start_time                      fid_                     Shape_Area
0   0.820108    2022-08-31T10:48:34Z    emit20220831t104834_o24307_s000       0.067763
1   0.962301    2022-08-27T12:25:06Z    emit20220827t122506_o23908_s000       0.067763
2   0.811369    2022-08-19T15:39:39Z    emit20220819t153939_o23110_s000       0.404882
3   0.788322    2023-01-29T13:23:39Z    emit20230129t132339_o02909_s000       0.404882
4   0.811369    2022-08-19T15:39:39Z    emit20220819t153939_o23110_s000       0.108256
```

^^Above is my original df that I will be working with.

Goal: I am hoping to create a new df that contains only the FIDs that meet the following conditions: If the shape area is equal, the cosi values have a difference greater than 0.1, and the start time has a difference greater than 5 days. This is going to be applied to a large dataset, the df displayed is just a small sample one I made to help write the code.

For example: Rows 2 & 3 have the same shape area, so then looking at the cosi values, they have a difference in values greater than 0.1, and lastly they have a difference in their start times that is greater than 5 days. They meet all set conditions, so I would then like to take the FID values for BOTH of these rows and append it to a new df.

So essentially I want to compare every row with the other rows and that's where I am having trouble.

I am looking for as much guidance as possible on how to set this up as I am very very new to coding and am hoping to get a tutorial of some sort!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "to create a new df that contains only the FIDs" - you mean a dataframe with a single column `fid`?

Comment: Yes, I guess essentially a list would work as well rather than a df.

Comment: you need to correct your description: you wrote *a difference **less** than 5 days ...*, then later : *... they have a difference in their start times that is **greater** than 5 days*

Comment: Just fixed it - it should've been greater than 5 days.

Comment: ok, for the input data you've presented there are NO groups of records that match all the needed conditions at one time. But the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75464504/3185459 will work for a more representative dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Group by `Shape_Area` and filter each pair (single items on `Shape_Area` are omitted) by required conditions:

```
fids = df.groupby('Shape_Area').filter(lambda x: x.index.size > 1 
                                                 and x['Cosine_i_'].diff().values[-1] >= 0.1 
                                                 and x['start_time'].diff().abs().dt.days.values[-1] > 5,
                                       dropna=True)['fid_'].tolist()
print(fids)
```

---